# how to set ticks axes text size using geom_boxplot in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, axis-labels

I´m trying with no success to increase the size of the status label (ticks labels yes/no) on the boxplot below.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
status <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 50, replace=T)
value <- rnorm(50, mean = 5, sd = 3)

data <- melt(data.frame(status, value),measure.vars="value")

p <- ggplot ( data, aes(x=status, y=value) ) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=10, outlier.size=4) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(colour=value), size=3, position = position_jitter(width = .3)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(min(data$value), max(data$value)),low="#0000FF", high="#FF0000") +
  labs(title="Title",x="status", y="value", colour="value")

p + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(5)), 
                       axis.title.x =element_text(size=10)
)

p
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you need to use axis.text rather than axis.title.

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
status <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 50, replace=T)
value <- rnorm(50, mean = 5, sd = 3)

data <- melt(data.frame(status, value),measure.vars="value")

ggplot(data, aes(x=status, y=value)) + 
  geom_boxplot(, outlier.shape=10, outlier.size=4) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(colour=value), size=3, position = position_jitter(width = .3)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_colour_gradient(limits=c(min(data$value), max(data$value)),low="#0000FF",     high="#FF0000") +
  labs(title="Title",x="status", y="value", colour="value")+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(5)), 
        axis.text.y =element_text(size=20))
```

Comment: have you tried to run it? Here, the plot does not respond to any changes of axis.text.y =element_text(size=10)

Comment: To be honest I don't put my ggplots into an object, so I wrote it like how I just edited above and the "yes" and "no" do change size.